# Is it possible to insert rel tags into WP widget heading elements?

Tags: wordpress, tags, widget, rel

Is it possible to insert individual rel tags into Wordpress widgets heading elements?

It is my intention to target the rel tags for CSS purposes.

Thank you

Colin

Answer (score 0):

When you register your sidebars (widget areas) there are arguments available to set html tags.

```
register_sidebar( array(
            'name'            =>"Sidebar Name",
            'id'              => "unique_sidebar_id",
            'description'     => "Your Description here",
            'before_widget'   => '<aside id="%1$s" class="your-classes %2$s">',
            'after_widget'    => '</aside>',
            'before_title'    => '<h3 class="widget-title" rel="your-rel">',
            'after_title'     => '</h3>'
        ));
```

The before_widget argument also runs a sprint_f that replaces `%1$s` with a unique id for each widget.